# Difference between CGAffineTransform on CIImage and UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview, core-image, cgaffinetransform, ciimage

I have been playing around with `CGAffineTransform` and noticed that transforming an image from the `UIImageView` has a different effect then transforming it directly through the `CIImage`. Here is the code:

```
let totalTransformationAndRotation = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: x)
// How I transform using the imageview
self.keyImage.transform = totalTransformationAndRotation
// How I transform using the image
var coreImage:CIImage? = myImage!.ciImage
if coreImage == nil {
   coreImage = CIImage(cgImage: myImage!.cgImage!)
}
coreImage = coreImage?.transformed(by: totalTransformationAndRotation)
```

When used separately these two transformations come out totally differently. I understand that the unit is different for the `CIImage`'s transformation's dx and dy and `UIImageView`'s transformation's dx and dy, but even rotations have a different result. It appears to me that when rotated in the `CIImage`. The rotation is centered around the bottom left, while in the `UIImageView` it is centered around the center of the image.

Is it possible to rotate, scale and translate a UIImage/CIImage and have the same effect as if you applied the same transformations on a UIImageView?

Edit:
I am trying to transform a `UIImage` by rotating, scaling, and translating. I have gotten the desired effect by applying a transforming on the `UIImageView`'s transform property but realized that I need to do the transformation directly in the image.

Comment: There is no such thing as a UIImage transform. Your example involves CIImage, a very different thing. If you want help doing an image transformation  please state clearly what the exact goal is. If you are just trying to draw the image rotated, I wouldn’t do it any of the ways you’ve shown so far.

Comment: Thanks, @matt I fixed it.

Comment: Ok but the CIImage is still not how I would do it. I would just redraw the image into an image graphics context with a transformed CTM. Again, I could demonstrate if you would be specific.

Comment: Or see my discussion at http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_graphics_context_transforms

Comment: @matt which one is faster? I may have to do hundreds of the transformations concurrently

Comment: Again you’re providing nowhere near enough real info. But rendering from a CIImage is very slow under normal circumstances, unless you are displaying with Metal.

Comment: @matt Is this more clear?

Comment: No. As I said, if you set me a specific problem I might demonstrate a way to do it. But so far this question is just so much hand waving.

Comment: There is some info in this documentation entry that I think you should consider very seriously: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/1437833-imagebycroppingtorect